# How to import certain Excel cells into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

I have begun work on a project where we'll be scanning a few hundred thousand forms and using some OCR software to create excel files of the scanned form.  I will then need to take certain cells from this spreadsheet and import them into SQL Server 2008.

The data in the spreadsheet is not in table form however.  The fields I need are scattered about.  For example name is in cell A3, ID Number in A11, Balance Due in A14, etc.

There is also a section of the spreadsheet that is in table form that holds dates in 3 columns (MM, DD, YY).  There could be any number of rows. So for example MM would be in A26, DD would be in B26 and YY would be in C26 and so on.

So what would be the best way to loop through all these files and import them into SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSIS(SQL Server Integration services) to import excel cells into SQL Server.